# How do I loop an equation through a range?

Tags: excel, vba

I am inserting a button into my excel program. I would like it to do two things: firstly to go through each row in the range and have the cell in one column (I) equal the other (H); secondly I would like the first column (H) to recalculate.

I have been able to have it work for one row, but I am struggling to loop it through the range and need some help.

```
Sub Button3_Click()

Worksheets("data").Range("i17").Value = Worksheets("data").Range("h17").Value
    Range("h17").Calculate

End Sub
```

I am looking for a way to have the above happen, but for range (i17:end of column). :-/

Comment: how is column H going to calculate when you are settings its value equal to column I? There will be no formula to calculate.

Comment: Hi Scott, I have a choose(randbetween(1,.... in h, so when I click the button I want the value of H to shift to I, and then for a new value to appear in H ready for me to click the button again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the values with the following command.

```
Worksheets("data").Range("i17").Resize(n,1).Value = _
                               Worksheets("data").Range("h17").Resize(n,1).Value
```

where `n` is the number of rows affected.

Then you can recalculate with

```
Worksheets("data").Range("h17").Resize(n,1).Calculate
```

Furthermore to find `n` use the following

```
Dim r as Range, n as Long
Set r = Worksheets("data").Range("h17")
n = r.Worksheet.Range(r, r.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

r.Offset(0,1).Resize(n,1).Value = r.Resize(n,1)
r.Resize(n,1).Calculate
```

Answer (score -1):

The below code will find the last row of data in column H and set all the values in the used range to equal column H then recalculate.

```
Sub Button3_Click()

With worksheets("data")

    Dim lr as Long
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count,"H").End(xlUp).Row

    With .Range("I17:I" & lr)
         .value = .offset(,-1).Value
         .calculate 
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Do not use string math as in `Range("I17:I" & lr)`. The correct way is to use the `.Offset()`, `.Resize()` and `.Cells()` methods under `Range` objects. It is much easier to maintain and understand, and it won't break if the cells move around. Finally writing each value one by one causes a recalculation each time and slows things down. Why not use **one** write operation to copy an entire table at once.